# How to test components where MatDialog is opened

Tags: angular

I have a MatDialog component that opens on successful signin. The onSignin function calls openDialog function. Here dialog is of type MatDialog

```
openDialog(statusCode: number, dialogData: Dialog) {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CustomDialogComponent, { data: dialogData })

  if (statusCode === 200) {
    dialogRef.disableClose = true
  }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
it('ask to log out if no parentUrl is found on signin', () => {
  const user = {
    id: '123'
  }


  spyOn(component.dialog, 'open')
  component.onSignin(user)
  fixture.detectChanges()

  const dialogData = new Dialog()
  dialogData.title = 'Logged In'
  dialogData.message = 'Your signin is successful.'
  dialogData.buttonTextPrimary = 'Log Out'
  dialogData.alertType = 'success'

  expect(component.dialog.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(CustomDialogComponent, {data : dialogData})
})
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'disableClose' of undefined
```

Here the dialogRef is coming as undefined. How can this be solved?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?